# Packing bottle orientation with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to detect the bottle orientation in a packing line, for this I'm using haar cascade with python opencv but I getting false positive detections.

This is the image that the system should detect as a positive:

[image]

But the problem is that the system will detect as a positive the following image:

[image]

Do you know is there is something better than haar cascade that I could use for this or how I could solve the issue with the false positive detection?

This is the complete code:

```
import cv2
import sys
cascPath = "cascadeedgedbottle.xml"
bottleCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    contrast =2
    brightness = 5

    bottle = bottleCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.05,
        minNeighbors=10,
        minSize=(125, 125),
        flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        #flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    print("Found {0} bottles!".format(len(faces)))

    # Draw a rectangle around the bottle
    for (x, y, w, h) in bottle:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: From a single example, it's impossible to give a good answer to this because it's wholly unclear what your requirements are: bottle shapes, colours, lighting, background, perspective, they all play a role.

Comment: Im completly new to computer vision so Im not very clear how haar cascade work but what I was thinking is that it could detect the shape of the bottle and knows when it is in the wrong direction that is image 1, so to answer your comment I was focusing in the bottle shape.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: HaarCascades might use shape only implicitly. If you want to continue with haarCascades I would suggest to train additional classifiers for the hole and the spout and check their number and order within the whole object.

Comment: Best general object detection can be achieved by neural networks like a yolo v4. Tiny yolo might be enough here.

Comment: A very basic CNN should do the trick here, if you have enough samples to train it.